# WAMP will not start Mongo driver. Updated: narrowed down the issue

Tags: php, mongodb

I have followed instructions down to the letter, but WAMP is not loading php_mongo.dll.

I have downloaded the latest version of WAMP and the MongoDB PHP driver, made sure I am using the correct versions and have also tried a few different versions, added lines to the php.ini file, but to no avail.

Currently I have:

- Wamp Server version 2.5, just did a clean install.
- MongoDB driver version 1.5.4-5.5 (thread safe) vc11 build for x86 (running 32 bit Windows).
- Renamed the file 'php_mongo.dll' and put it in the standard extension directory (C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext).
- Added the line extension=php_mongo.dll to the php.ini file and checked it stays there after saving and closing the file.
- Ensured that it appears in the list of extensions and is ticked on the Wamp control panel.

But I can't get it to show by using phpinfo(), so I assume that means it cannot start. Every tutorial says to 'make sure you're using version x or stable release y'. I have tried about 15 different combinations and this is the closest I have got.

Can anyone help?

**UPDATE:**

Got rid of WAMP as I wanted finer control. I've got Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.4.12 working great, but Mongo is still not playing ball. I've checked the server logs and it's giving me this line:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_mongo.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

When I used a different version of the driver I got an error saying it wasn't a valid win32 program, but now it's saying that (even though that file DOES exist).

Comment: Did you check the php/server startup logs to see if anything gets logged? e.g. using a threadsafe driver in a non-threadsafe PHP may not work.

Comment: The error log repeats this line a lot: [14-Jul-2014 14:42:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[14-Jul-2014 14:42:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0

Apparently WAMP will only allow thread safe extensions anyway.

Comment: Did you work out the issue with installing the MongoDB extension?